# JavaScript issue on using Array.includes() and test duplicate items

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, fetch

I have an input that uses an API to fetch some cities based on the letters inserted. The API is launched on each `keyup` event like so :

```
let ville_input = document.getElementById("search_immobilier_ville");
let ville_arr = [];

ville_input.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  res_list.innerHTML = "";

  fetch("https://api.fr/communes?nom=" + ville_input.value)
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(el => {
        if (
          el.codeDepartement == "971" &&
          el.nom
            .toUpperCase()
            .startsWith(ville_input.value.toUpperCase().trim())
        ) {
          if (!ville_arr.includes([el.nom, el.codesPostaux[0]])) {
            ville_arr.push([el.nom, el.codesPostaux[0]]);
            console.log(ville_arr);
          }
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Doing stuff
    });
});
```

First of all I want to push each results as arrays into an array like so :

```
ville_arr.push([el.nom,el.codesPostaux[0]])
```

My issue is that I get duplicate items into my array when the API fetch the same result, that is why I tried this :

```
if(!ville_arr.includes([el.nom,el.codesPostaux[0]])){

    ville_arr.push([el.nom,el.codesPostaux[0]])
    console.log(ville_arr)

      }
```

But I still get duplicate items in the end, I guess it has something to do with the indexes of the array which are unique ? maybe something else ?

[image: Here's a result example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const ville_input = document.getElementById('search_immobilier_ville');
let ville_arr = [];
ville_input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    res_list.innerHTML = '';

    fetch(`https://api.fr/communes?nom=${ville_input.value}`)
        .then(res => {

            // Clear old data if get new response
            ville_arr = [];

            return res.json();
        })
        .then(...)
        .catch(...);
});
```

OR try use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (and extra info about [find vs some](https://jsperf.com/js-array-some-vs-find) on jsPerf.com):

```
if(!ville_arr.find(i => i[1] === el.codesPostaux[0])) {

    ville_arr.push([el.nom, el.codesPostaux[0]]);
    console.log(ville_arr);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) does a referential equality check for objects.

This means that, even though you are pushing objects of the same shape, they are not the same references because each request creates a new object.

The usual pattern is to remember some uniquely identifying part of an object instead, like an id.

Maybe you can store and check for the zipcode instead?

```
if (!zipcodes.includes(el.codesPostaux[0])) {
  zipcodes.push(el.codesPostaux[0]);
  ville_arr.push([el.nom, el.codesPostaux[0]]);
}
```

A time-efficient method is to use a set of zipcodes instead of an array (because set lookup time is O(1)):

```
if (!zipcodesSet.has(el.codesPostaux[0])) {
  zipcodesSet.add(el.codesPostaux[0]);
  ville_arr.push([el.nom, el.codesPostaux[0]]);
}
```

If you decide to use the `ville_arr` only, then what you need could also be done using [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) (or [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)):

```
// this will return true if every place in ville_arr
// does not have the zipcode from the response
if (ville_arr.every(([, zipcode]) => zipcode !== el.codesPostaux[0])) {
  ville_arr.push([el.nom, el.codesPostaux[0]]);
}
```

You could also potentially call `JSON.stringify` over your object to create the same string from a certain object and save that which would work because `includes` does equality comparison for primitive values such as strings.

Answer (score 1):

`Array#includes` does not compare reference types by their values; it compares them to check whether their references are the same.

For example, this produces `false`:

```js
var myArr = [[5, 6], [1, 2], [4, 5]];

console.log(myArr.includes([1, 2]));  // false
```

because the `[1, 2]` array on line 1 is not the same array as the one on line 3, even though they contain the same values.

To deal with this, you can instead use `Array#some`, which accepts a lambda function:

```js
var myArr = [[5, 6], [1, 2], [4, 5]];

console.log(myArr.some(e => e[0] === 1 && e[1] === 2));  // true
```

Or to put this in terms of your specific example:

```
if(!ville_arr.some(e => e[0] === el.nom && e[1] === el.codesPostaux[0])) {
    ville_arr.push([el.nom,el.codesPostaux[0]])
    console.log(ville_arr)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another "old school" way of doing it could be this: declare an object (`o`) and add sub-arrays to it with a key generated from the contents of each array. This object will then keep its unique structure by itself:

```
var o={d:{},add:function(nom,code){this.d[nom+code]=[nom,code]},
get:function(){return Object.values(this.d)}};
```

You add values to it with

```
o.add(el.nom, el.codePosteaux[0]);
```

and retrieve the unique array from it with

```
o.get()
```